# Vibrating my iphone until i tell it to stop

Tags: ios, objective-c

I found tons of posts about how to vibrate for an interval. At first, I thought this was what I needed. But my needs are different, I need to vibrate until a condition is met. I have a drawing pad, its called a Slate - I want my phone to vibrate while the pen is on the pad, ie, when someone is drawing on it.

**PSEUDO CODE OF WHAT I DESIRE**

```
while (pen is touching)
 vibrate
```

Here is my "touch moved"

```
- (void)touchMoved:(CGPoint)point
```

Comment: There is likely a reason why it isn't easily done;  most likely, that'll destroy battery life.

Comment: I believe that. I just wonder if it's actually possible.

Answer (score 0):

There's a method in AudioToolbox framework which enables to make the phone vibrate and catch the end of such event. I would then use a recursive method to keep vibrating till I need it;

```
@property (assign) BOOL keepGoing;

...

-(void)penDidStartDrawing{
    self.keepGoing = YES;
    [self justVibrate];
}

-(void)penDidStopDrawing{
    self.keepGoing = NO;
}

- (void) justVibrate{
    if( self.keepGoing ){
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSoundWithCompletion(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate, ^{
            [self justVibrate];
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Any way to do this in a "flow" as opposed to one beat at a time?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no public API which enables you to do that. I know my solution may not seem so elegant but I don't think there is a simplier way.